# How to fix loop condition?

Tags: c++

so basically im working on an assignment for battleship The main function calls the fire function in a loop.  Inside this loop the fire function is called once for each player.  After each execution of this function the game board parameter is changed (see above) to reflect the result of the player's move.  Also, in main the value in the end_game parameter must be evaluated to determine if the player has indicated that the game should be terminated.  This evaluation must also include a determination of whether a player has won the game (ie. the no_hits parameter is equal to 23).

but also their is a function called the winner_test function which is supposed
The main function must use the winner_test function to make the determination of whether there has been a winner yet.  To do this the winner_test function simply determines if either no_hits_player_1 or no_hits_player_2 is equal to 23.  There are 23 positions that contain ships on each board.  So when there has been 23 hits on either board, the game has been won and the program should end.

my question is the winner test function necessary and in my loop the condition to keep iterating is if the end_game parameter is true if it is false it means the user entertained the values 10 10 which is supposed to end the loop my question is my loop condition wrong and if so how could i fix it my code is below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
typedef char gameBoard[10][10];
using namespace std;
const int MAX_ROWS = 10;
const int MAX_COLS = 10;
void get_board_data(ifstream&, gameBoard, gameBoard);
void fire(gameBoard, int&, bool&);
void print_board(gameBoard);
bool winner_test(int, int);
int currentplayer = 1;


int main()
{
    int no_hits;
    bool end_game = true;
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("infile.txt");
    gameBoard Player1;
    gameBoard Player2;
    get_board_data(myfile, Player1,Player2);
    //The main function calls the fire function in a loop.  Inside this loop the fire function is called once for each player.
    while (end_game==true) {
        fire(Player2, no_hits, end_game);
        if (end_game == false)
        {
            break;
        }
        fire(Player1, no_hits, end_game);

    }

}


void fire(gameBoard player, int& no_hits, bool& end_game)

{
    int row;
    int col;
    static int player1_hits=0;
    static int player2_hits=0;
    if (currentplayer == 1)
    {
        cout << "Player 1 hits:" << " " << player1_hits << " "<< "player2  hits:" << " " << player2_hits << endl;
        cout << "Player 1 - enter your move" << " " << "(ie. 0 4)";
        cin >> row >> col;
        if (row == 10 && col == 10)
        {
             end_game = false;
             return;
        }

        if (player[row][col] == '#') {
            cout << "hit!!!!!" << endl;
            player[row][col] = 'H';
            player1_hits++;
            currentplayer = 2;
        }
        else if (player[row][col] == '-')
        {
            cout << "miss!!!" << endl;
            player[row][col] = '.';

        }
        currentplayer = 2;

    }
    else if (currentplayer == 2)
    {
        cout << "Player 2- enter your move" << " " << "(ie. 0 4)";
        cin >> row >> col;
        if (row == 10 && col == 10)
        {
            end_game = false;
        }

        if (player[row][col] == '#') {
            cout << "hit!!!!!" << endl;
            player[row][col] = 'H';
            player2_hits++;
            currentplayer = 1;
        }
        else if (player[row][col] == '-')
        {
            cout << "miss!!!" << endl;
            player[row][col] = '.';
            currentplayer = 1;

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Man, this code is too long. We don't need all of this, just give us the minimum necessary to help you

Comment: ... ensuring that it meets the definition of a [MCVE].

Comment: It looks like you forgot to `return` when player 2 inputs `10 10`. Just another example of why you should  avoid repeating code. Making any change means remembering to make the same change in any number of other places.

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  A debugger will help you execute each statement singly and *watch* the values of variables.  Please edit your post with the results of your debugging session.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer this the best I can.  It sounds like your `winner_test_function` is just checking the amount of hits a player has made which makes sense.  Your second question about the loop condition is a little confusing to me, and if I understand it it makes sense, but it's just not how I would approach this problem.  Basically your saying the only way the game can end is if the `player_hits` is equal to 23 or the user types in 10 10.  I'm wondering why would you want the user to be able to end the program by entering something in?  Shouldn't the program only end if a player hits all the ships?  I maybe missing something, but it seems like that is what your saying.  If you want them to be able to end the program by entering 10 10 then what your doing will work, but like @Andrieux said it wont work int the `currentPlayer == 2` if statement because you are missing the return statement.

```
should be end_game = false;
return;
```

A side note: Why are you making statements like `cout << "Player 2- enter your move" << " " << "(ie. 0 4)";`. The `<< " " <<` part is irrelevant.  Just write it as `cout << "Player 2- enter your move (ie. 0 4)";`